# Skip loop to populate form if result array from mysql query is empty

Tags: php

Suppose `$datas` is the result array of a MySQL query. (I'm using "medoo" mySQL PHP class.) If I load the page setting a parameter as 'index.php?edit=804' I populate the form like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $datas = $database->select("events", "*", ["id[=]" => $id]);
    } 

    foreach ($datas as $data) {
?>
        <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $data['field1'] ?>">
        <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?php echo $data['field2'] ?>">
 <?php
     }
 ?>
```

But if I don't want to set any parameter and simply load a blank form I get

```
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

or, if I declare `$datas` as an empty array (as suggested) the form is not shown at all.

How can I skip the `foreach` if `$datas` is empty without using a `if - then - else` clause that would double the lines of code? The following would be ridiculous:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($datas) {
        foreach ($datas as $data) {
?>
            <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $data['field1'] ?>">
            <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?php echo $data['field2'] ?>">
<?php
        } else {
?>
            <input type="text" name="field1">
            <input type="text" name="field2">
<?php
    }
?>
```

**If the loop is simply skipped the form is not rendered.**

Comment: Set `$datas` as empty array when there's no result in your function or wherever you get it.

Comment: an empty array is a valid argument for `foreach`

Comment: just make sure that `$datas` is declared as `array` even when its empty before hand, then you wouldn't need to add the if condition

Comment: You can't have a default if you don't use an if case.Either you have a blank foreach because of empty array or you use an if case to make sure that you have a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it without using if else

```
foreach((!empty($datas) ? $datas : ['field1' => '']) as $data =>$value) 
{   ?>

<input type="text" name="field1" value="<?=$value ?>">
<input type="text" name="field2" value="<?=$value ?>">
<?php
}
```

This one you will get your 2 empty fields.

Answer (score 2):

An empty array is a valid argument for a `foreach` loop, you could send an array with empty values in case `$datas` is not what you expect:

```
foreach((is_array($datas) ? $datas : [['field1' => '', 'field2' => '']]) as $data) {
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $data['field1'] ?>">
    <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?php echo $data['field2'] ?>">
    <?php
}
```

This way you will get your 2 empty fields.

Comment: As explained in my edited post, the form is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the needed keys of the variable is empty or not an array.

```
<?php
if (empty($datas) || !is_array($datas)) {
    $datas = ['field1'=>'', 'fields2'=>''];
}

foreach ($datas as $data) {
?>
     <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $data['field1'] ?>">
     <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?php echo $data['field2'] ?>">
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add simple - `if (!empty($datas) !== FALSE)`

```
<?php
    if (!empty($datas) !== FALSE){
        foreach ($datas as $data) {
?>
            <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $data['field1'] ?>">
            <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?php echo $data['field2'] ?>">
<?php
    }} else {
?>
            <input type="text" name="field1">
            <input type="text" name="field2">
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: You do not need to double anything, just add simple !== FALSE to check whethever skip this and show blank form.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..

Don't use foreach loop.

There is no need to use a loop as you've already using the indexes.

Simply use this...

```
<input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $datas['field1'] ?>">
<input type="text" name="field2" value="<?php echo $datas['field2'] ?>">
```

Even if `$datas` is empty The form would be empty...
If there are any values in `$datas` then the values will be printed in the form...